# Flags in Python

Tags: python, matrix, numpy, flags

I'm working with a large matrix (250x250x30 = 1,875,000 cells), and I'd like a way to set an arbitrary number of flags for each cell in this matrix, in some manner that's easy to use and reasonably space efficient.

My original plan was a 250x250x30 list array, where each element was something like: `["FLAG1","FLAG8","FLAG12"]`. I then changed it to storing just integers instead: `[1,8,12]`. These integers are mapped internally by getter/setter functions to the original flag strings. This only uses 250mb with 8 flags per point, which is fine in terms of memory.

My question is: am I missing another obvious way to structure this sort of data?

Thanks all for your suggestions. I ended up rolling a few suggestions into one, sadly I can only pick one answer and have to live with upvoting the others:

EDIT: erm the initial code I had here (using sets as the base element of a 3d numpy array) used A LOT of memory. This new version uses around 500mb when filled with `randint(0,2**1000)`.

```
import numpy

FLAG1=2**0
FLAG2=2**1
FLAG3=2**2
FLAG4=2**3

(x,y,z) = (250,250,30)

array = numpy.zeros((x,y,z), dtype=object)


def setFlag(location,flag):
    array[location] |= flag
def unsetFlag(location,flag):
    array[location] &= ~flag
```

Comment: How many flags do you need to support?

Comment: I'm not sure, I wouldn't be confident saying anything more accurate than "more than 5 and less than 500".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would generally use a [numpy](https://numpy.org/) array (presumably of short ints, 2 bytes each, since you may need more than 256 distinct values) -- that would take less than 4MB for the <2 million cells.

If for some reason I couldn't afford the numpy dependency (e.g on App Engine, which doesn't support numpy), I'd use the standard library [array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) module - it only supports 1-dimensional arrays, but it's just as space-efficient as numpy for large homogeneous arrays, and the getter/setter routines you mention can perfectly well "linearize" a 3-items tuple that's your natural index into the single integer index into the 1-D array.

In general, consider numpy (or array) any time you have large homogeneous, dense vectors or matrices of numbers -- Python built-in lists are highly wasteful of space in this use case (due to their generality which you're not using and don't need here!-), and saving memory indirectly translates to saving time too (better caching, fewer levels of indirection, etc, etc).

Comment: Thanks for the numpy suggestion. One question about the data type. Since a ushort can hold values up to 2**16, can't I only have 16 flags if I use ushort?

Comment: Sorry... I was still thinking of bitflags as in a previous answer. I see what you mean now, a 4d array, where a[0][0][0] would return a 1d array correct?

Comment: Hmm, I had read your question differently, with just a single flag (or none) per cell (with up to 500 different values), as opposed to up to 500 flags for a single cell. For your actual question a 4-D array (with 512 bits per cell, 64 bytes) is indeed needed, so that's 128 MB (and the translation to/from bit by shift and mask, as other answers have mentioned) -- *IF* you do need to be as "dense" as that (if the _typical_ cell has a few flags, then lists are again attractive, esp. in numpy where you only need lists at the lowest level).

Comment: Thanks for this idea. I've ended up using a 3d numpy array of sets (on the assumption that a set is better suited for this than a list).

Comment: erm, sets sucked. Sample code I pasted in the question uses the magic of python long's. Thanks for the numpy array tip.

Answer (score 7):

Your solution is fine if every single cell is going to have a flag.  However if you are working with a sparse dataset where only a small subsection of your cells will have flags what you really want is a dictionary.  You would want to set up the dictonary so the key is a tuple for the location of the cell and the value is a list of flags like you have in your solution.

```
allFlags = {(1,1,1):[1,2,3], (250,250,30):[4,5,6]}
```

Here we have the 1,1,1 cell have the flags 1,2, and 3 and the cell 250,250,30 have the flags 4,5, and 6

edit- fixed key tuples, thanks Andre, and dictionary syntax.

Comment: He's using a three dimensional matrix, so you would need so say something like dict((1,1,1)=[1,2,3]...

Comment: Actually, shouldn't that be {(1,1,1):[1,2,3], ...).  dict(key=val) syntax only works if your keys are python identifiers.

Answer (score 5):

You can define some constants with different, power of two values as:

```
FLAG1 = 0x01
FLAG8 = 0x02
FLAG12 = 0x04
...
```

And use them with boolean logic to store the flags in only one integer, p.e.:

```
flags = FLAG1 | FLAG8
```

To check if a flag is enabled, you can use the `&` operator:

```
flag1_enabled = flags & FLAG1
```

If the flag is enabled, this expression will return a non-zero value, that will be evaluated as True in any boolean operation. If the flag is disabled, the expression will return 0, that is evaluated as False in boolean operations.

Comment: This saves me about 20% of the required memory even if I use up to 100 objects, very interesting! One question, how do I remove a flag?

Comment: Maybe not the best approach if you really might have up to 500 flags, although Python does support arbitrarily long integers.

Comment: To remove a flag you have to add its negation (flags &= ~FLAG1)

Comment: @Alex Jurkiewicz: new_flags = old_flags & ~flags_to_remove.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. Although I'm going to use sets instead of bitfields (I don't need the extra space savings here) I definitely will need something like this in future.

Comment: Actually, I am! see sample code in the question, and thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using Flyweight pattern to share cell properties:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern

Answer (score 1):

[BitSet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_array) is what you want, since it allows you to store many flags at once using only an fixed size integer (Int type)

Answer (score 1):

Taking Robbie's suggestion one step further...

```
flags = set()
x, y, flag = 34, 201, 3
flags.add((x, y, flag)) # set flag 3 at position (34, 201)
if (3, 2, 1) in flags: # check if flag 1 is at position (3, 2)
    # do something
else:
    # do something else
```

You can also create a helper class.

```
class Flags(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = set()
    def add(self, x, y, flag):
        self.data.add((x, y, flag))
    def remove(self, x, y, flag):
        self.data.remove((x, y, flag))
    def contains(self, x, y, flag):
        return (x, y, flag) in self.data
```

You could also implement Python's special methods like `__contains__` to make it easier to work with.